# GWT: The requested URL /testlogin/greet was not found on this server

Tags: gwt

I am very new in GWT and sorry for my poor English.

I have google compile project, build project, and then debug as web application in my localhost, and it works fine.

But now I want to deploy it to Centos, I have done the debug configuration but it come with an error "The requested URL /testlogin/greet was not found on this server." 

Here is the link http://peugeot/TestLogin.html, just login as any username(password field just let it blank) then the error come out.

I have tried build a .war and put it the web server but it still same

Can anyone help? I spent few days already, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run a GWT App with server communication then you have to deploy it on a Webserver like Tomcat. Server communication wont work if you just put the war-file into the www folder.

Comment: through Tomcat first and put file into my Centos server is it?or mean that i need a Tomcat it Centos? Sorry that i am also new in Tomcat ==

Comment: install tomcat(if its not already there) on your centos server: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-centos-7-via-yum  then put the compiled war file into the webapps folder of your tomcat